# CSS tags not all is working on my browser

Tags: css

There is a problem when it got to css coding in my PC(Version 83.0.4093.3 (Official Build) dev (32-bit)) because not all of tags on css works on my google chrome but my code is correct.

I'm not sure if my chrome is connected to my problem.

Comment: Can you post the part of the code which is not working for you?

Comment: add in your css

Comment: And clarify what "not all is working" means exactly.

Comment: Hi Piolo, Please post some code, snapshots and explain in detail as to what is happening exactly